# Should we have examples of social events as tags as well as the tag "Social Event"?

Tags: discussion, tags

As stated in the question, are tags such as [dance](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dance) and [party](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/party) necessary, or should we aim to remove them, using the [social-event](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-event) tag instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem with having both tags.  [social-event](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-event) would refer more to general questions that would apply in a variety of settings, whereas [party](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/party) or [wedding](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wedding) or [funeral](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/funeral), etc., would refer to questions that are specific to those events.

That said, I see nothing preventing in certain circumstances that a question be tagged with both if the question would apply generally to a variety of social events, but more specifically to a certain event.

**My vote: make specific tags for questions that refer to a specific social event.**

Comment: Agreed. If a question is about a specific event, then there should be a relevant tag, not social-event tag.